# Columns are not displaying as desired

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="well">column1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="well">column2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

this my body this should display two coloums side by side, 
however this is not displaying side by side, its displaying 
one after another please see the screen shot
```

[image]

```
how to fix this could you please tell me ?
```

=======================================================================================================================================================================================================

**below is the complete source**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title Page</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                column1
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                column2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: It depends on the Width of the Browser window since it is Responsive. https://jsfiddle.net/3d7gz892/

Comment: screenshot not included!

Comment: @Adam P, added the image

Answer (score 0):

> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful mixins for generating more semantic layouts.

[Bootstrap's Grid System documentation.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

If you want to have 2 columns next to each other on different browser sizes you should use `xs` classes.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="well">Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="well">Column 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/bBgVJv)

Comment: Look at the example.

Comment: I saw the example which is working right, I don't know why my local setup is not working .................Thanks for responding

Comment: added the complete source html

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap using a 12-column grid** computing, so if you only need two columns will also be counted to 12 columns!

For example: 02.10; 6/6; 4/8; etc

jsfiddle.net/kga1h3yo/1/

Comment: @ Adam P. , 
I saw the example which is working right, I don't know why my local setup is not working .................Thanks for responding

Comment: If you attach the source of the page you see in your browser (right click-> Show page source (or something similar)), it may turn out to see where the error!

Comment: The complete source code (doctype, <head> section, etc.) should see, not only the "<body> and </body>" between tags!